# How to handle multiple photos in one message using TelegramLongPollingBot?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I am developing telegram bot on Java that should handle sending message with multiple photos to it.

The problem that per what I understood message with multiple photos technically recognised as separates message (one message - one photo).

So, when I use class Bot that extends `TelegramLongPollingBot` and override `onUpdateReceived` to get messages from telegram bot, I get `Update` object, in which there is `Message` object and `Message` object consists `Photo` object (list of different sizes for current image).

Is there a way to determine that multiple messages with photos related to one message? Or combine them in one `Message` to handle it in `onUpdateReceived`?